# Spring boot, allowing POST access to static content

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-boot

I am using spring boot and because we are using a 3rd party authentication process access to our index.html page is redirected to a POST request.

When the post requests comes in (for example index.html) on my spring boot application i get this error:
"Method Not Allowed, Request method 'POST' not supported".

I have tried to use RestControllers to redirect to GET requests or configure the ResourceHttpRequestHandler (supportedMethods property) but I just cant get it to work.

So either i need to be able to configure spring boot to allow POST methods by default for static context or to write a RestController to serve the HTML page.

Example code is very simple

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class Example {

   public static void main(String[] args) {
       ApplicationContext ctx = SpringApplication.run(Example.class, args);
   }
}
```

Put any index.html page into resources/static and run the app and try to access the page with a POST request and not a GET request.  This is to simulate my application having a POST redirect from a single sign on provider POSTing the SAML or OpenID tokens as the request payload.

Thanks

Comment: Have any example code? It's hard to know what's wrong when we don't know what your doing.

Comment: Just follow this.  https://spring.io/guides/gs/spring-boot.  Remove the HelloController and add a html file in the resource/static folder.  After running the application, requesting get http://localhost:8080 is fine, requesting post http://localhost:8080 returns the error.

Comment: Well yes and it should... a POST is for modification a GET is for getting resources. That is how the HTTP spec is intended to work.

Comment: I am using Ping Federate (https://documentation.pingidentity.com/display/PF610/SP-Initiated+SSO--Redirect-POST) to allow SSO into my application.  Once the redirect has happened to the identity provider it needs to POST the request back to the index.html page to provide the payload of the SAML or OpenID token as part of the request, this is very common.   Tomcat works with allowing POST request for static content.  This is all that I need.  These are not rest services.

Comment: I'm having this same issue with my IdP POSTing the SAML tokens back to the index.html that spring boot is serving as static content and not allowing POSTs to it. Were you ever able to find a solution to this?

Comment: I have the same issue. Did you find any solution? Thx

Comment: I am having same issue with spring-boot 2, when IDP tries to do a POST request to my static content, it fails with 405 Method Not Allowed. Any solution? @GlenD